# Falha ao compilar projeto Android Studio :app:packageDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > Entry name 'res/animator/linear_indeterminate_line1_head_interpolator.xml' collided
```

A build é feita com sucesso mas quando vou gerar apk ou mandar para meu dispositivo da esse erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Tenta fazer um "Clean Project" como na imagem abaixo.
- Execute o aplicativo novamente, se caso ainda ocorrer o erro, vá na sua pasta:
  res -> animator
- Encontre o xml "linear_indeterminate_line1_head_interpolator.xml", remove ele se não for necessário, e caso for necessário tente encontrar o mesmo arquivo duplicado no File Explorer (As vezes não aparece no Android Studio), se não houver nenhum, renomeie ou até mesmo crie novamente fazendo "Clean Project" a cada processo.

[image: cleanning gradle]